# How to determine if the predictive text is on or off for edit text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a edit text in my application. Soft keyboard pops up when edit text gains focus. User can switch predictive text on / off by selecting soft keyboard predictive text feature on or off. I want to determine if the predictive text is on/off when
keyboard pops up.

Please Help.

Regards,
Krishna Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `isSuggestionsEnabled`:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mET);
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        if(hasFocus){
            boolean suggestions = et.isSuggestionsEnabled();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @ Archie, Thanks for the response but this gives false even if soft keyboard has predictive text on